# Start the counter when the div scrolls into the view

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, frontend, counter

So, I have the counter, that goes from 0 to the certain number.
The div that includes the counter is far below on the page - when the user gets there, the counter will most likely have already reached the maximum number and stopped.
How do I trigger the function when the counter div scrolls into the view?

Answer (score -1):

There's a jQuery script that performs actions when an element is in the viewport called [jQuery inview](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview). Link it to your HTML file then use the following to bind an event when the div is inview.

```
function increment() {
    $('div').one('inview', function (event, visible) {  //one animates it once
        if (visible == true) {
            // element is now visible in the viewport
            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                $('#number').text(number);
                if (number >= target){
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
                number++;
            }, 50);
        } else {
            // element has gone out of viewport
        }
    });
}
$(window).on("load", increment);
```